# WPF Loading CustomDictionary File at AppData\Local\Temp Failed

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, textbox

Good morning,

I'm a newbie to posting issues on the site; I always find the answers without problem.  This one, however, is persistent and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.  This is a spontaneous issue and doesn't affect all users.

The following error appears:
"Loading custom dictionary file at C:\Users\Someuser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfile.tmp failed."

Here is the code that I use to add the custom dictionary file to the textbox upon initialization.

```
IList<Uri> dict = (IList<Uri>)SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries;
dict.Add(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/ResourceDictionary/medicalDictionarySpellCheck.lex"));
```

I cleared temp directories thinking that there was some kind of space limitation that was blocking the creation of a temp file necessary in the process.  It didn't slow the error down.

This mostly happens in the afternoon after the program has been in use for several hours.  One thing I did notice is that the users have a screen capturing program that does fill up the temp directory, but this error appears even with almost no files in the folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: use FileInfo either use GetTempPath() you can create dictionary and store your things into particular folder